# Condition for equality of two terms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's assume we have two terms,

$$\frac{a^HA_1a}{a^HA_2a} \quad\text{and}\quad a^HA_1A_2^{-1}a,$$

where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix and $a$ is an $n\times 1$ vector. In which condition they are equal ?

Comment: That first fraction arises often in statistics in cases where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are symmetric idempotent matrices whose product is $0$. (When you divide the fraction above by the ratio of ranks of the two matrices, you get a statistic that has an $F$-distribution if the appropriate null hypothesis holds.)  But the second expression doesn't arise in those statistical problems since you can't invert any symmetric idempotent matrix execpt the identity matrix.

Comment: you mean just when $A_2$ is identity two terms are equal and there is no other condition for equality of two terms

Comment: Well assuming $a$ is normalized then the sufficient condition if $a$ is eigenvector for both $A_{1,2}$ (I assume $A_{1,2}$ are symmetric).

Comment: Moreover, it is enough for $a$ be only an eigenvector of $A_2$.

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner can you proof it?

Comment: I gave it in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is not complete it gives only sufficient condition. 
Assume $a$ is normalized and $A_{1,2}$ are symmetric; Then we have:
$$
a^T A_1 a= a^T A_1 A_2^{-1} aa^T A_2 a
$$
which is equivalent to :
$$
a^TA_1A_2^{-1}(I-aa^T)A_2a=0
$$
To make satisfy  this equality is enough to assume that 
$$
(I−aa^T)A_2a=0
$$
This can be true if $A_2a=\lambda a$
I don't see more general weak and simple assumptions. 
Of course $A_1 a=0$ is 1 more trivial sufficient condition.